# + and - 12 V power supply with 12v Batteries, How to make a ground rail with both batteries

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, battery-operated, photodiode

I'm  new to electronics. I want to make a battery supply to power an OPT301M {photodiode with integrated op amp} and an ADTL082 dual {op amp IC} in order to attempt to reduce noise in the circuit. I have two 12V batteries and I'm assuming I just connect the positive terminal of one battery to the + rail and the - terminal of the other battery to the - rail and the remaining battery terminals connect to the ground rail. I'm going to use a 3 amp fuse on each battery for safety. I'm quite a noob so there might be something obvious I'm missing here or doing completely wrong

Comment: connect the middle terminal (where the two batteries are joined) to ground, that way one battery makes +12 and the other makes -12 - I think I'm saying the same thing you are, just in a different order.

Answer (score 2):

> I have two 12V batteries and I'm assuming I just connect the positive terminal of one battery to the + rail and the - terminal of the other battery to the - rail and the remaining battery terminals connect to the ground rail.

That's the correct way to do it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9i00L.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The schematic version.*

> I'm going to use a 3 amp fuse on each battery for safety.

Good idea.

> I'm quite a noob so there might be something obvious I'm missing here or doing completely wrong.

It looks fine so far.